# Sending IPA file to Beta testers. Do I need to do this after every version change?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I've just created my first IPA file and I'm ready to send it to Beta testers. I'm going to send them an email with the file and the instructions I found in:

[image]

Now, my question is, after making some change to the app and changing the version in `General`settings of `project`, I need to create a new archive and new `ipa`file?

Do I need to send the new `ipa`to testers over email again? Do they need to connect their devices to `iTunes`in order to update to the newer version?

I know of some tools like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com), I just want to make sure if I need them or if I can manage to do this without these third party tools. I would like to know if it is possible for testers to update to newer versions without needing to connect device to computer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to resend them the app and they'll need to install it using iTunes or iPhone configuration utility.
Unless you turn it into an Enterprise app (temporarily) in which case it can be downloaded from a web server etc.

TestFlight is pretty good and you could consider it as its quick and easy to start using, however they got acquired by Apple last week and its not currently possible to download their SDK.

Comment: TestFlight's definitely the way to for beta test distribution.  I'm not having issues downloading the SDK right now, but perhaps that's because I have an existing account.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't notify your beta testers about update without 3rd party tools. You have to build/archive new version each time and broadcast it (via email) to your testers. Testers can update your application by connecting their device to computer (iTunes) and transferring new version of application to iTunes (they can just Ctrl+Drag .ipa file to iTunes). After this step, the application can be found in iTunes library. Testers should drag new version of your app in "iDevice library" so that it will appear in the list of (new) applications to install or applications to update. After that there will be an **Update** button to update your application to new version directly from iTunes.

Comment: Since Apple has bought TestFlight, lets hope they will come up with something useful and well integrated for distributing apps.